# Deserializing JSON field with possible choices using serde

Tags: json, rust, enums, serde

I'm trying to use serde json deserialization to  support "choices"  using enum, but it doesn't seep to be working (I have python enum background)
let's say I have this json :

```json
{"name": "content", "state": "open"}
```

and `state` can be `open` or `closed`

in python I would just create an enum and the state type would be that enum eg:

```rust
#[derive(Deserialize)]
enum State {
    Open(String),
    Closed(String),
}

#[derive(Deserialize)]
struct MyStruct {
    name: String,
    state: State,
}
```

and the problem is that I don't know how to derserialize `open` to `State::Open` and `closed` to `State::Closed`
I have looked into implementing my own deserializer, but it seems very complicated and very advanced for me.

is there any straightforward way ?

Comment: What the `String` inside will contain?

Comment: sorry I was just trying different combinations here is the error without `String`  `Error("unknown variant `open`, expected `Open` or `Closed`", line: 1, column: 32)'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove the `String`. Then you'll get another error:

```
unknown variant `open`, expected `Open` or `Closed`
```

Because your enum variants are in PascalCase while your JSON is in camelCase (or snake_case, I don't know). To fix that, add [`#[serde(rename_all = "camelCase")]`](https://serde.rs/container-attrs.html#rename_all):

```rust
#[derive(Deserialize)]
#[serde(rename_all = "camelCase")]
enum State {
    Open,
    Closed,
}
```